# Constraints\Callback annotation validate the previous (not submitted) entity

Tags: forms, validation, symfony

I'm using a [Callback](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html) to validate an entity

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\Foo")
 * @ORM\Table(name="foo")
 * @Constraints\Callback(methods={"validate"})
 */
class Foo
{
    ...

    function validate(ExecutionContextInterface $context)
    {
        if ($this->foos) {
            $context->buildViolation('Foos cannot be emty')
                ->atPath('foos')
                ->addViolation();
    }
}
```

A form is using this entity:

```
class FooFormType extends AbstractType
{
    private $foosService;

    function __construct(FoosService $foosService) {
        $this->foosService = $foosService;
    }
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('foos', EntityType::class, array(
                'label' => false,
                'class' => 'AppBundle:Entity\Foo',
                'choices' => $this->foosService->getSomeFoos($builder->getData()),
                'expanded' => true,
                'multiple' => true,
                'required' => true,
            ))
            ->getForm();
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Foo',
        ));
    }
}
```

This form is called within a factory:

```
public function getFooForm(Foo $foo)
{
    return $this->formFactory->create(new FooFormType($this->foosService), $foo);
}
```

Finally, in the controller:

```
...

$form = $this->get('my_factory')->getFooForm($foo);
$form->handleRequest($request);
if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
    $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();
    ...
}

...
```

This seems to work correctly, but **the validation is being done over the previous entity**. I mean, if I submit empty `foos` I can see the validation error, but if I sumbit some `foos`, and then I remove those `foos`and submit again, the validation doesn't throw any exception because it's being done over the last entity, which had some `foos`. I've checked that the submitted data is correct, and indeed, `Foo` entity is been persisted with empty `foos` (only if the previous one had `foos`).

What can be causing this weird behaviour?